# how to convert list to dataframe with special format in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

so i have a list that looks like

```
my_list
[[1]]
     "a" "b"
[[2]]
     "c"  

#corresponding to time vector 
time
2000 2001
```

and i also know the factor vector

```
factor
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
```

How to I convert this list to a dataframe that looks like:

```
year  on_off  factor
2000   TRUE     a
2000   TRUE     b
2000   FALSE    c
2000   FALSE    d
2001   FALSE    a
2001   FALSE    b
2001   TRUE     c
2001   FALSE    d
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: @akrun if it is in the list of corresponding index. so mylist[[1]] correspond to 2000 where we only have a and b, so a and b is true, c and d is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, year = 2000:2001, 
  lapply(my_list, \(x) as.data.frame(table(factor(x, levels = letters[1:4]))))))
names(out)[2:3] <- c("values", "on_off")
out$on_off <- as.logical(out$on_off)
```

-output

```
> out
  year values on_off
1 2000      a   TRUE
2 2000      b   TRUE
3 2000      c  FALSE
4 2000      d  FALSE
5 2001      a  FALSE
6 2001      b  FALSE
7 2001      c   TRUE
8 2001      d  FALSE
```

#### data

```
my_list <- list(c("a", "b"), "c")
```

Comment: is it possible not to hardcode FALSE TRUE? in the real dataset I have like 100

Comment: @skw123 try the update

Comment: sorry for keep adjusting the question, if the factor is a vector of abcd, and year is also a vector of 2000, 2001, what needs to be changed ?

Comment: You just need to change `year = 2000:2001` to `year = youryearvec` and the `levels = yourabcdvector`

Comment: thank you, i will update the question to reflect our comment